# Is $\frac{1}x\cos\left(\frac{1}x\right)$ Lebesgue integrable on $[0,1]$?

Tags: measure-theory, functions, lebesgue-integral

I have to decice if the following function is Lebesgue-integrable on $[0,1]$:

$$g(x)=\frac{1}x\cos\left(\frac{1}x\right) $$ where $x\in[0,1]$.

Comment: Use the substitution $t = 1/x$ and follow the same steps as in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/390841/4583).

Comment: But I can't use Riemann as in the example

Comment: You can use the monotone convergence theorem to show that the Lebesgue integral is the limit of the Riemann integral in the example.

Comment: @AymanHourieh: The Riemann integral exists, because the improper Riemann integral is defined as
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to0+}\int_\epsilon^1\frac1x\cos\left(\frac1x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
However, [the Lebesgue integral requires that the integral of the absolute value exist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral#Improper_Riemann_integrals_and_Lebesgue_integrals).

Comment: @robjohn Yes. I'm aware of this. The answer I linked to considers the integral of the absolute value.

Comment: @AymanHourieh: I was referring to the comment that "the Lebesgue integral is the limit of the Riemann integral in this example" which seems to say that the Lebesgue integral exists. I must be misunderstanding that comment.

Comment: @robjohn Perhaps my comment was a bit vague. The Lebesgue integral I was referring to was the integral of the absolute value of the function. Since the limit of the Riemann integral of the absolute value goes to $\infty$, the Lebesgue integral doesn't exist indeed.

Comment: @AymanHourieh: okay, that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\int_{\large\frac1{n\pi}}^1\left|\frac1x\cos\left(\frac1x\right)\right|\,\mathrm{d}x
=\int_1^{n\pi}\left|\frac1x\cos(x)\right|\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
However, $\left[\frac\pi2,n\pi-\frac\pi2\right]\subset[1,n\pi]$ and
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{\pi/2}^{n\pi-\pi/2}\left|\frac1x\cos(x)\right|\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\int_{k\pi-\pi/2}^{k\pi+\pi/2}\left|\frac1x\cos(x)\right|\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&\ge\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac2{(2k+1)\pi}\left|\int_{k\pi-\pi/2}^{k\pi+\pi/2}\cos(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right|\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac4{(2k+1)\pi}
\end{align}
$$
and since the Harmonic Series diverges, $\frac1x\cos\left(\frac1x\right)$ is not Lebesgue integrable on $[0,1]$.

Comment: I don't understand why do you chose that values for the interval of the integral. Could you explain it please?

Comment: @Blanca: I have added some to my answer that may help to explain. If not, let me know.