# Show that,$\int_0^\pi \left|\frac{\sin nx}{x}\right|\mathrm{d}x \ge \frac{2}{\pi}\left(1+\frac12+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}\right)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Show that,$$\int_0^\pi \bigg|\dfrac{\sin nx}{x}\bigg|\mathrm{d}x \ge \dfrac{2}{\pi}\bigg(1+\dfrac12+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{n}\bigg)$$

I could not approach the problem at all. Please help.

Comment: The zeros of $\sin nx$, where it changes sign, are $\dfrac{k\pi}{n},\; k = 0,\,1,\,\dotsc,\,n$. Splitting the integral and looking at each part alone ought to help.

Comment: @DanielFischer Let me try...thank you for the hint...

Comment: @DanielFischer I got the representation as you said...but, would I need to evaluate each and every integral or I would need to get another function which looks similar to the above function but is less than or equal to the above expression to get the inequality?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/390841/4583

Comment: @AymanHourieh I would really appreciate it a lot if you could post a solution here without using the summation notion. I face very much difficulty to conceive the representation with summation.

Comment: @Hawk Did you try to expand the sums yourself? Converting from one notation to another is purely mechanical.

Answer (score 8):

$$
\begin{align}
I &=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \int_{i\pi/n}^{(i+1)\pi/n} \frac{|\sin{nx}|}{|x|}\,dx \\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \int_{0}^{\pi/n} \frac{|\sin{nx}|}{i\pi/n+ x}\,dx \\
&\gt \sum_{i=1}^{n} \int_{0}^{\pi/n} \frac{|\sin{nx}|}{i\pi/n}\,dx \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{2/n}{i\pi/n} \\
&= \frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i}
\end{align}
$$