# How should i solve this one? It would be great if it doesnt imply advanced calculus theory

Tags: integration, inequality

$$\int_{\pi} ^{2 \pi} \frac{|\sin(nx) |} {x} dx\geq\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+k}$$
I've tried to use basic inequalities such as $$x-\frac{x^{3}}{6} < \sin(x), \quad $$ but it doesn't seem to help. Trying to approximate the right hand sum to ln(2) also didnt help. Please, show me a way to solve it

Comment: Try to take a look at the Wallis product.

Comment: Same idea as here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/683576/show-that-int-0-pi-left-frac-sin-nxx-right-mathrmdx-ge-frac2-pi?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: There could be another way, but that does seem to be the easy way to do it, if you get the right result (which I suspect you will).

Comment: Could you present it? I complicated it so much that i cant think of an easy method

Comment: @Jack Vlad Matei's link works.