# convergence dominate of Lebesgue-Application

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

my question is: let $f(x)= \dfrac{\sin (nx)}{x}.\varphi(x)$, where $\varphi \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$. We can found an function $g \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ such as $|f(x)| \leq g$? Please.
I think that, supposing that $Supp(\varphi) \subset [-a,a]$ with $a>0$. We have 
$$
|\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}} \dfrac{\sin (nx)}{x}.\varphi(x)|\leq C \displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}} |\dfrac{\sin(nx)}{x}|dx
$$ where $C=\sup_x|\varphi(x)|$. then since $\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}} |\dfrac{\sin(nx)}{x}|dx=\pi$, there exist $g(x)= \dfrac{\sin(nx)}{x} dx \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Is it correct?

Comment: What is the "original" limit problem?

Comment: there is no limit problem, i search if we can majorate $f$ with an function $g \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: Then see my answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrong, $\sin(x)/x\not \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. We have that
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}dx=\pi\quad\text{and}\quad
\int_{\mathbb{R}} \left|\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}\right|dx=+\infty.$$
See [Evaluating the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x} x \ dx = \frac \pi 2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5248/evaluating-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-sin-x-x-dx-frac-pi-2) and [Improper integral $sin(x)/x $ converges absolutely, conditionaly or diverges?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390810/improper-integral-sinx-x-converges-absolutely-conditionaly-or-diverges) .

On the other hand, since $|\sin(x)|\leq |x|$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, it follows that 
$$\left|\dfrac{\sin (nx)}{x}\cdot \varphi(x)\right|\leq n|\varphi(x)|$$
and  $g=n|\varphi|\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$.