# A very challenging question integral of an infinite product.

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product, trigonometric-series

Evaluate:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\sqrt{\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(θ/2^k)+1}{2}}dθ.$$

This was a problem from the book 'S.P.Patterson's Rectreational Problems in Advanced Mathematics'.
The problem was included in the 'Additional problems' section and did not have the solution.

I don't even know where to start.
I thought of first decomposing the infinte product into an integrable function of  $θ$, but I don't know how to .

Even wolfram alpha was not able to comprehend it..

If you have a solution, please do share it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. Note that
$$\sqrt{\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(θ/2^k)+1}{2}}=\left|\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}\cos(θ/2^{k+1})\right|$$
then use [Finding the limit $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\ (\cos \frac x 2 \cdot\cos \frac x 4\cdot \cos \frac x 8\cdots \cos \frac x {2^n}) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455995/finding-the-limit-lim-limits-n-to-infty-cos-frac-x-2-cdot-cos-frac) and see [Improper integral $\sin(x)/x $ converges absolutely, conditionaly or diverges?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390810/improper-integral-sinx-x-converges-absolutely-conditionaly-or-diverges)

Comment: How do you evaluate $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx?$$

Comment: There's a lot of way https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_integral

Comment: @RyanScott The second link in my answer explains why $\int_{0}^{\infty}\left|\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right|dx=+\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sin\pars{\theta} & = 2\sin\pars{\theta \over 2}\cos\pars{\theta \over 2}
\\
\sin\pars{\theta} & = 2^{2}\sin\pars{\theta \over 4}
\cos\pars{\theta \over 4}\cos\pars{\theta \over 2}
\\
\sin\pars{\theta} & = 2^{3}\sin\pars{\theta \over 8}
\cos\pars{\theta \over 8}\cos\pars{\theta \over 4}\cos\pars{\theta \over 2}
\\
\vdots\phantom{AA} & \,\,\vdots\phantom{AAAAAAAAAAAAAA}\vdots
\\
\sin\pars{\theta} & = 2^{n}\sin\pars{\theta \over 2^{n}}
\cos\pars{\theta \over 2^{n}}
\cos\pars{\theta \over 2^{n - 1}}\cdots\cos\pars{\theta \over 2}
\\[5mm] \implies & 
\bbx{\prod_{k = 0}^{n - 1}\cos\pars{\theta \over 2^{k + 1}} =
{\sin\pars{\theta} \over 2^{n}\sin\pars{\theta/2^{n}}}}
\\[5mm] \implies &
\bbx{\prod_{k = 0}^{\infty}\cos\pars{\theta \over 2^{k + 1}} = {\sin\pars{\theta} \over \theta}}
\end{align}