# Evaluate the $\int_0^\infty\frac{|\sin t|}{t}\;dt$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

When I saw $$\int_0^\infty\frac{|\sin t|}{t}\;dt$$ integral I remembered Laplace transform and complex analysis but I couldn't find anything. Is this integral bounded (convergent) and if it is what is it's value?
I cannot do anything.

Comment: This integral diverges, as you can see from $\int_0^\infty \frac{|\sin(x)|}{x}\ge \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(k+1)\pi}\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}|sin(x)|dx=\frac{2}{\pi}\sum\frac{1}{k+1}=\infty$

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390810/improper-integral-sinx-x-converges-absolutely-conditionaly-or-diverges)